# Python requests login

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am still fairly new to python and have some questions regarding using requests to sign in. I have read for hours but can't seem to get an answer to the following questions. If I choose a site such as www.amazon.com. I can sign in & determine the sign in link: https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html...

I can also find the sent form data, which includes items such as:

```
appActionToken:
appAction:SIGNIN
openid.pape.max_auth_age:ape:MA==
openid.return_to:
password: XXXX
email: XXXX
prevRID:
create:  
metadata1: XXXX
```

my questions are as follows:

1. When finding form data, how do I know which items I must send back in a dictionary via post request. For the above, are email & password sufficient, and when browsing other sites, how do I know which ones are necessary?
2. The following code should work, but doesn't. What am I doing wrong?
3. The example includes a header category to determine the browser type. Another site, such as www.slashdot.org, does not need the header value to sign in. How do I know which sites require the header value and which ones don't?

Anyone who could provide input and help me sign in with requests would be doing me a great favor. I thank you very much.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
data = {'email':'xxxxx', 'password':'xxxxx'}
header={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = session.post('https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html', data,headers=header)
print response.content
```

Comment: You will first need to 'get' the url to maintain the cookies. Apart from that, you will need to send other parameters as well in post data.

Answer (score 1):

> When finding form data, how do I know which items I must send back in a dictionary via post request. For the above, are email & password sufficient, and when browsing other sites, how do I know which ones are necessary?

You generally need to either (a) read the documentation for the site you're using, if it's available, or (b) examine the HTML yourself (and possibly trace the http traffic) to see what parameters are necessary.

> The following code should work, but doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

You didn't provide any details about how your code is not working.

> The example includes a header category to determine the browser type. Another site, such as www.slashdot.org, does not need the header value to sign in. How do I know which sites require the header value and which ones don't?

The answer here is really the same as for the first question.  Either you are using an API for which documentation exists that answers this question, or you're trying to automate a site that was designed primarily for human consumption via a web browser, which means you're going to have figure out through investigation, trial, and error exactly what parameters you need to provide to make the remote server happy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My code isn't logging in successfully. I receive the same login page whether I use correct login credentials or not. So somehow the logic of my code is incorrect.